# Strange `UnicodeEncodeError` using `os.path.exists`

Tags: python, apache, unicode, flask

In a web-application (using Flask), I get the following error:

```
Unable to retrieve the thumbnail for u'/var/data/uploads/2012/03/22/12 Gerd\xb4s Banjo Trio 1024.jpg'
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/www/beta/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dblib-1.0dev3-py2.7.egg/dblib/orm/file.py", line 169, in get_thumbnail
   if not exists(filename):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 18, in exists
   os.stat(path)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb4' in position 52: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Note that I include the `repr()` of the file name in the logged error. This shows that the file name is passed as a Unicode instance. So much is correct...

If I run the culprit using the python interpreter, it works as expected:

```
>>> from os.path import exists
>>> exists(u'/var/data/uploads/2012/03/22/12 Gerd\xb4s Banjo Trio 1024.jpg')
True
```

So obviously, while running in the Flask environment, Python thinks it should encode the file-name using the ASCII codec instead of UTF-8. I deployed the application using mod_wsgi behind the Apache httpd.

I assume I have to tell either one of them to use UTF-8 somewhere? But where?

Comment: Don't think this is the proper solution, but when in similar situations I find myself using 'string'.encode('utf8') does the trick - might be worth a shot.

Comment: I'm sure it's a configuration issue. So, until I figured out the right setting I simply guarded it with a try/except block peppering me with emails every time it occurs :P It's an error and I want to be reminded of it :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See Django docs for same issue. When using mod_wsgi, should be same solution:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#if-you-get-a-unicodeencodeerror

Excerpt from the above linked doc:

> [...] you must ensure that the environment used to start Apache is
>   configured to accept non-ASCII file names. If your environment is not
>   correctly configured, you will trigger UnicodeEncodeError exceptions
>   when calling functions like the ones in `os.path` on filenames that
>   contain non-ASCII characters.
>
> To avoid these problems, the environment used to start Apache should
>   contain settings analogous to the following:
>
> ```
> export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
> export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
> ```
>
> Consult the documentation for your operating system for the
>   appropriate syntax and location to put these configuration items;
>   `/etc/apache2/envvars` is a common location on Unix platforms. Once
>   you have added these statements to your environment, restart Apache.

Comment: Just a note: the anchor you're referring to doesn't seem to exist in that URL anymore. Instead I found it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#if-you-get-a-unicodeencodeerror

Comment: In `uwsgi.ini` it must not contain quotes: `env = LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: In my case, I added `env = LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in `uwsgi.ini`, according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/#s-configuring-and-starting-the-uwsgi-server-for-django